# How can I format data as the user types?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, handsontable

In my HandsOnTable have a column that is our SKU.  We format these as 99-9-999.  How do I setup a mask or can I make it insert the dashes as the user types?  I've tried a custom editor and renderer without success.  I'm really looking to change the value on `keyup`.

Comment: that's a tough one since i'm not sure there're events on the editors for things such as on keyup. i wonder if you could somehow attach the keyup event when an editor is opened, and remove it when closed. I would post this on the github page so that the devs can add it as a feature or at least point you to the Editor code where you may be able to add this event

Comment: There's a Jquery plugin called masked input if that's what you were looking for. [here's the link](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Comment: I've tried the jquery mask but it seems to only work for input and not td.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for this case regular expressions. Something like that:

```js
var fnf = document.querySelector("input");
fnf.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {  
   let val = evt.target.value;
    var n = (val.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3"));
    console.log(n)
    fnf.value = n.toLocaleString();
}, false);
```

```html
<input value="121-212-121-212-1212" placeholder="SKU">
```